# White Flickering When Transitioning Between Screens

Tags: swiftui

I've been working on a SwiftUI app for quite some time now and now that I have built out all of my screens I decided to start stitching them together with NavigationView and NavigationLinks. However, I noticed this awfully annoying bug when transitioning between views and opening the app. The edges (primarily the left edge) flicker white during the transition, and it's extremely annoying.

I have a feeling that this is because SwiftUI may be using a pure white background behind my views and when animating it's not perfectly aligned with my custom view. Therefore, the misalignment causes this flickering but this is just my hypothesis.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I could fix it? I'm developing for iOS 16 and use the following pattern for all of my core views:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Background()
            Content()
        }
    }
}

private struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Main content of the view
    }
}

private struct Background: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

I have also uploaded a video showcasing this bug here: https://emalm.com/?v=YXrZP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this issue and to be honest, I couldn't see it in your video either. Maybe it has something to do with the screen that is being used for Xcode / video replay. So be sure to try it on a real device, to confirm that it really happens on a physical device.

Anyway, it seems you are ignoring the color scheme on the device (light or dark) and always applying a black background. So it might help, to apply `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` to a high level view, such as the app's `ContentView` or the `NavigationStack`. The default system background color will then be black instead of white for that view and everything below it.

Comment: I'm not sure how you don't notice the flickering in the video as it looks very obvious to me and everyone else I've shown. However, I have also been noticing this for quite some time so I'm sure it's much more obvious for me now.

I tried using `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` and that seems to do the trick! It does introduce some other coloring related issues into my app that I don't understand but I think this is the right path moving forward. Thank you.

Comment: .preferredColorScheme(.dark) fixed it for me as well.

Even setting .background(Color.black) as an alternative doesn't fix it as well as setting the color scheme to dark. It's interesting, I wonder what is going on.